# I want to send data to influx database using expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect, influxdb

I want to send data to influx database using expect script. I tried to use spawn command as shown below but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

```
spawn sh -c "curl -i -XPOST http:www.xyz.com/write?db=db --data-binary 'measurement1,async=true field=0'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interacting with the curl command you don't need `spawn`.  It will be simpler to use `exec` - see documentation at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm .  Try:

```
exec curl -i -XPOST http:www.xyz.com/write?db=db --data-binary {measurement1,async=true field=0}
```

If this fails, post the exact error message you get.